# header If-Modified-Since does not give 304 code

Tags: python

I am using below code to save an html file with a time stamp in its name:

```
import contextlib
import datetime
import urllib2
import lxml.html
import os
import os.path
timestamp=''
filename=''
for dirs, subdirs, files in os.walk("/home/test/Desktop/"):
    for f in files:
        if "_timestampedfile.html" in f.lower():
            timestamp=f.split('_')[0]
            filename=f
            break
if timestamp is '': 
    timestamp=datetime.datetime.now()

with contextlib.closing(urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(
        "http://www.google.com",
        headers={"If-Modified-Since": timestamp}))) as u:
    if u.getcode() != 304:
        myfile="/home/test/Desktop/"+str(datetime.datetime.now())+"_timestampedfile.html"
        file(myfile, "w").write(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read())
        if os.path.isfile("/home/test/Desktop/"+filename):
        os.remove("/home/test/Desktop/"+filename)
        html = lxml.html.parse(myfile)
    else:
        html = lxml.html.parse("/home/test/Desktop/"+timestamp+"_timestampedfile.html")

links=html.xpath("//a/@href")
print u.getcode()
```

When I run this code every time I get the code 200 from If-Modified-since header. Where am I doing mistake? My goal here is to save and use an html file and if it is modified after last time it is accessed, html file should be overwritten.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `If-Modified-Since` is [supposed to be](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25) a [formatted](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1) date string:

```
If-Modified-Since: Sat, 29 Oct 1994 19:43:31 GMT
```

but you're passing in a datetime tuple.

Try something like this:

```
timestamp = time.time()
...
time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT', time.gmtime(timestamp))
```

---

The second reason your code isn't working as you expect:

http://www.google.com/ does not seem to honor `If-modified-since`.  That's allowed per the RFC, and they may have various reasons for choosing that behavior.

> ```
>   c) If the variant has not been modified since a valid If-
>      Modified-Since date, the server SHOULD return a 304 (Not
>      Modified) response.
> ```

If you try http://www.stackoverflow.com/, for example, you'll see a 304.  (I just tried it.)

Comment: Now I am using datetime.datetime.now().ctime() which is giving me time in this format Wed Jul 24 16:16:19 2013, still not working. Is there any way I can get time in the format you have suggested.

Comment: That [`ctime` output] is not the right format, either.  It must be formatted precisely like "Sat, 29 Oct 1994 19:43:31 GMT".  I've updated my answer to include some sample code that generates a conformant value. Hope that helps!

Comment: Still not working, now I am giving time in this format Wed, 24 Jul 2013 23:37:11 GMT

Comment: That time format looks good (note that I had a bug in my `strftime` format, which I've fixed).  But there's another problem: http://www.google.com/ does not appear to honor If-modified-since.  Thats's their prerogative.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes you are right, Still I am not getting 304 code but an http Error 304: not modified. By using error handling I have managed it. Thank you very much